# How to get Package ID given a package name via AzureDevOps REST API

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-artifacts

If I have just the package name, is it possible to get the package ID using a single API call. Looks like Package ID is required for any further API calls - to get versions of a package etc.,

Or is the only way to get all the packages from the feed, match with the name and then get the ID from that?

Reference API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details/get%20package?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a `packageNameQuery` query parameter in the [Get Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details/get%20packages?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api to retrieve the package's information with a given name.

```
GET https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/packages?protocolType={protocolType}&packageNameQuery={packageNameQuery}&normalizedPackageName={normalizedPackageName}&includeUrls={includeUrls}&includeAllVersions={includeAllVersions}&isListed={isListed}&getTopPackageVersions={getTopPackageVersions}&isRelease={isRelease}&includeDescription={includeDescription}&$top={$top}&$skip={$skip}&includeDeleted={includeDeleted}&isCached={isCached}&directUpstreamId={directUpstreamId}&api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

For Organization scoped feeds:

```
$url= "https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedid or feedName}/packages?packageNameQuery={package Name}&api-version=6.0-preview.1"
```

For Project scoped feeds:

```
 $url= "https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedid or feedName}/packages?packageNameQuery={package Name}&api-version=6.0-preview.1"
```

See below example:

```
#Organization scoped feed
$url= "https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedid or feedName}/packages?packageNameQuery={package Name}&api-version=6.0-preview.1"

$PAT="Personal Access Token"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))

$ArtInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method get
```